# How to embed other app in another one and overlay some layout

Tags: java, android, view

first of all, hi!
secondly, this question is not same as other "embed app in app" question because i have an example of an app that does this and still being developed until now it is blocklauncher by zhouweizhang and also there is a github page that shows its source code.

The idea:
I was trying to make an app that can embed a game and some sort of making a floating action button or just a button to take screenshots easily and other tools.

And blocklauncher uses System.load to load the game's library and createPackageContext. is those functions is what i need?

some other question answered by "It is not possible ... " etc.
but there is blocklauncher.

btw. the link to github page:
https://github.com/zhuowei/MCPELauncher/

Comment: It is definitely not possible in general. Most of the other questions of this variety are for trying to embed an arbitrary app. It might be possible in limited cases, for particular apps, with periodic crashes. Please note that the code is not "still being developed until now", as that repository has not been updated in nearly four years. And, by reading the project README, it appears that you will need a lot more than "System.load to load the game's library and createPackageContext", such as root access. Plus, there is the issue of whether what you propose is legal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: legal? maybe not. Updated? Yes, on google play. Crashes? true. Afterall I have other app doing MAYBE something just like this. it is Samsung's game tools however it does something different. rather than embedding other app it show a floating action button. was this the same one?